# Does Blender allow encoding to .webm?

Tags: rendering, video, encoding

I'm trying to export a mp4 video as a .webm, but the render animation does literally nothing.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or whether it's even possible to export as .webm?

Comment: Blender 2.81 has, or so the manual says, webm as an FFmpeg container.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update 2**

[Lukasz-40sth](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/40129/lukasz-40sth) is right Blender 2.81 has a WEBM container which eliminates all the previous issues. It also supports the Opus audio codec. These features were added by [Dr. Sybren Stüvel](https://developer.blender.org/D5156) based on FFmpeg which implements the container and codecs.

[image: WEBM container]

---

**Update**

While the output described in the configuration below does output a video that is playable by all major browsers, it doesn't follow the guidelines for WEBM. For instance the [WEBM Container Guidlines](https://www.webmproject.org/docs/container/) specify that:

> `DocType` element SHOULD be "webm"

However Blender's output has `DocType` set to `matroska` when using the Matroska container. I assume that *SHOULD* in this context refers to the meaning specified in [RFC 2119](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119), it's recommended but not a must. The file should therefore still be a valid WEBM.

---

*Disclaimer: I'm not very familiar with video container formats, the following information may be inaccurate.*

Blender 2.80 doesn't have a dedicated WEBM container, however [WEBM is a subset of the Matroska container format](https://www.webmproject.org/docs/container/) that only allows a specific set of audio and video codecs. Therefore you should be able to produce a valid WEBM with the following settings:

- *Container*   : **Matroska**
- *Video Codec* : **WEBM / VP9**
- *Audio Codec* : **Vorbis**

The output file will have the .mkv extension which you can rename to .webm.

[image: Settings]

---

When you have created your video in the VSE and then use *Render Animation* to export the video, it will be stored in the directory that is specified in the *Output* panel (for example in the screenshot it's `/temp`). Make sure that you're checking in the correct directory.