# Rendering animation with transparent background for website

Tags: rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine, transparency, video

I need to render animation with transparent background in Eevee and then to put that up on my website so video format has to be supported by HTML. Can I do that in blender?

Comment: Hello, could you tell us which video formats are supported by HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not know of any way to render transparent video *directly* in blender, but you can fairly easily render a transparent png image sequence and use other software such as [Filestar](https://filestar.com/skills/png/convert-png-to-webm) to convert in into webm

Just remember to turn on transparency in the render properties' film settings and use RGBA when you export the sequence so it includes transparency

Edit: Turns out you can indeed render webm directly in blender, it's just hidden under a couple of dropdowns, thanks brockmann

Comment: Blender allows direct encoding to WEBM: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/151008/can-you-export-a-mp4-as-webm-with-the-new-blender-2-8-update